# What are the rules on switching leaders?

Tags: state-of-decay-2

I have a couple of closely related questions, which I'll combine into this one post.

1. How can you switch leaders? Do you have to kill/exile your current leader, or is there another way? If I switch maps, does my leader reset?
2. If I build a leadership building, and then switch to a new leader type, does my leadership building go away? Or can I have multiple leadership buildings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For question 1:

- You can't actually switch leaders, your current leader must be disposed of by either exiling or death before a new leader can be chosen.
- Switching maps does not reset your leadership position in your community but does reset the legacy missions I believe.

For question 2:

- You keep the leader facility and all its functionalities. This means that if you have multiple different leaders in 1 playthrough, you could acquire multiple leader facilities if you have enough big slots and do not destroy it or move to a new base.

> The effect of removing a leader from his or her position is
>   surprising, because the leader is a requirement for the building, just
>   like water, power or knowledge of a specific skill. Usually, when one
>   of your survivors with a certain knowledge is removed from the group,
>   any facilities that depended on its knowledge will no longer have all
>   actions available anymore or won't provide all passive effects
>   anymore. So I'm unsure if the current effect is as planned or a bug at
>   the moment. Only future patches will reveal this.

Comment: I tested #2. This proved to be false. I killed my sheriff, but still can use the special abilities of the field hospital.

Comment: @Evorlor I hadn't tested it myself, but I assumed it would be like that because I had experienced it with the farm and an agriculture survivor. I'll scrap it from my answer. Not sure if its a bug though or intended.

Comment: @Evorlor I have updated my answer